# How to load all entries in an infinite scroll (lazy-loading) to parse the HTML in Java

Tags: java, html, web-crawler, jsoup

I have a probelm when using Jsoup to crawl a website which uses lazy-loading and Jsoup can't access enough the content i need. Is there any ways to solve it?

I'm using selenium and FirefoxDriver to get but it's not enough

```java
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Downloads\\Compressed\\geckodriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);   
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get(URL);
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: I have no errors but the result isn't enough as what i need

Comment: It would be nice to know the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, the phrase you are using "lazy loading" sounds like the site is making AJAX calls back to the server to retrieve the content that is displayed into your browser.  I have done a lot of webpage parsing - but actually executing Java-Script (natively, like a browser does) is not something I can do with my code yet.  I have read a lot about Selenium, but I have not used it.

One of the comments in your comment section asked about the URL of the site you are scraping...  If you were to manually look at the page HTML, it might be possible to identify the names of the Java-Script methods that are being called, and then use those methods, in Java, to call the server and get the content yourself...

This is, indeed, from what I have read is what Selenium WebDriver is supposed to do automatically (execute Java-Script natively on the DOM) with a "headless browser.".  But I have scraped many sites content by finding the JavaScript method names, making a 2 line Java Program to call the server itself and then parse the HTML or JSON myself to do whatever I need to do with it...